# Python 2.7 parsing data

Tags: python, parsing, tree

I have data that look like this:

```
data = 'somekey:value4thekey&second-key:valu3-can.be?anything&third_k3y:it%can have spaces;too'
```

In a nice human-readable way it would look like this:

```
somekey    : value4thekey
second-key : valu3-can.be?anything
third_k3y  : it%can have spaces;too
```

How should I parse the data so when I do `data['somekey']` I would get `>>> value4thekey`?

Note: The `&` is connecting all of the different items

**How am I currently tackling with it**

Currently, I use this ugly solution:

```
all = data.split('&')
for i in all:
    if i.startswith('somekey'):
        print i
```

This solution is very bad due to multiple obvious limitations. It would be much better if I can somehow parse it into a python tree object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split the string by `&` to get a list of key-value strings, and then split each such string by `:` to get key-value pairs. Using dict and list comprehensions actually makes this quite elegant:

```
result = {k:v for k, v in (part.split(':') for part in data.split('&'))}
```

Comment: You could change it to `{k: v for k, v in (part.split(':')...)}`

Comment: @NChauhan True 'dat. That's definitely more elegant - edited it in to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your data directly to a dictionary - split on the item separator `&` then split again on the key,value separator `:`:

```
table = {
    key: value for key, value in 
    (item.split(':') for item in data.split('&'))
}
```

This allows you direct access to elements, e.g. as `table['somekey']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have objects within a value, you can parse it to a dictionary

```
structure = {}

for ele in data.split('&'):
    ele_split = ele.split(':')
    structure[ele_split[0]] = ele_split[1]
```

You can now use structure to get the values:

```
print structure["somekey"]
#returns "value4thekey"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the keys have a common format of being in the form of "key":"value".
You can use it as a parameter to split on.

```
for i in x.split("&"):
      print(i.split(":"))
```

This would generate an array of even items where every even index is the key and odd index being the value. Iterate through the array and load it into a dictionary. You should be good!

Answer (score 0):

I'd format data to YAML and parse the YAML

```
import re
import yaml

data = 'somekey:value4thekey&second-key:valu3-can.be?anything&third_k3y:it%can have spaces;too'
yaml_data = re.sub('[:]', ': ', re.sub('[&]', '\n', data ))
y = yaml.load(yaml_data)
for k in y:
        print "%s : %s" % (k,y[k])
```

Here's the output:

```
third_k3y : it%can have spaces;too
somekey : value4thekey
second-key : valu3-can.be?anything
```